# Localhost as ssh bridge between two server

Tags: bash, ssh, rsync

I can connect via ssh to two hosts, say host1 and host2 and I need to copy files from host1 to host2 via `rsync`.

I know I can realize this first copying files from host1 to localhost and then from localhost to host2 or perform simple copy via `scp -3 <user1@host1:/file_path1> <user2@host2:/file_path2>`, but my goal is test ssh tunnel via `rsync`.

Someone can help me?

**Extra:**

I've read about ssh tunnel, but can't reach my goal... probably there's something I've don't understood. For example if I run

```
$ ssh -L 9999:host2:22 user_host1@host1
```

this means: map my local port 9999 to port 22 of host2 and connect to host1 as user user_host1 but... with this mapping what's the purpose of connect to host1 ?

Comment: The tunnel should be configured e.g. on host1 to reach host2 through (what you called localhost) a third computer that can connect to both host1 and host2. Otherwise, you need remote port forwarding. I suggest you read more [about it](https://blog.trackets.com/2014/05/17/ssh-tunnel-local-and-remote-port-forwarding-explained-with-examples.html).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, thanks to **mmv-ru**: your answer was a great start-point to find what was wrong in my case.

I've write an answer to explain step by step what to do:

#### 1 Remote Loopback

in one console run `ssh -R 127.0.0.1:9999:host2:22 user_host1@host1 -N`

#### 2 Work on remote

in other console goto server host1 `ssh user_host1@host1` and then run

```
rsync -e "ssh -p 9999" /file_path1 user2@127.0.0.1:/file_path2
```

in my case this command fails, because I need:

1 - add `[127.0.0.1]:9999` to my known hosts by clicking yes

2 - since I ssh to host2 via a single key, I need to add that key into host1 and set it' permissions to 400.

So my command is

```
rsync -e "ssh -p 9999 -i my_ssh_key_for_host2" /file_path1 user2@127.0.0.1:/file_path2
```

and works!!!

#### 3 ALL IN ONE

after **step 2** (creation key for host2 on remote host1) I can perform all with one command:

```
ssh -R 127.0.0.1:9999:host2:22 user_host1@host1 'rsync -e "ssh -p 9999 -i my_ssh_key_for_host2" /file_path1 user2@127.0.0.1:/file_path2'
```

> Note single quote in second part!

Regards,

Sim

Answer (score 0):

- Assume You unable to connect ssh directly from host1 to host2. (Otherwise simplest is direct connect host1 to host2)
- Assume it impossible to connect from host1 or host2 to Your PC.

Next Command make rsync

```
ssh -R 127.0.0.1:9999:host2:22 user_host1@host1   rsync -e "ssh -p 9999" /file_path1 user2@127.0.0.1:/file_path2
```

Lets parse it:

- ssh make connection to host1
- `-R 127.0.0.1:9999:host2:22` listen on remote (host1) loopback at port 9999 and forward connection over client host to host2:22
- on host1 rsync run
- `-e "ssh -p 9999"` force using non default ssh port for connection
- rsync local path `/file_path1` to remote path `user2@127.0.0.1:/file_path2` we make connection to user2@host2 but as address we use mapped earlier loopback port

I hope not mistyped in command.

**UPD**

For troubleshooting try at first connect interactive ssh with tunnel

```
$ ssh -R 127.0.0.1:9999:host2:22 user_host1@host1
```

and manual ssh connect over tunel

```
[user_host1@host1 ]$ ssh -p 9999 user_host1@127.0.0.1
```

Tunneling can be disabled in sshd config at host1.

Comment: Unfortunately this configurations doesn't works: I receive the message `ssh: connect to host 127.0.0.1 port 9999: Connection refused`, but I'm sure I can connect to both host: I've added ssh keys to ssh-agent.

Comment: I checked. It works on my hosts.